# Replace NaN in dataframe during merging / left join

Tags: python, pandas, merge, fillna

I am merging two dataframes together as a left join. However, if the value in a specific column is either blank or NaN, I'd like to replace that value from the "right" dataframe (and only in that case. Otherwise, I want to ignore the 'Cost' data in df2)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
         'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
         'Version':[1,1,2,2,1,2],
         'Cost':[17,np.nan,24,21,'',8]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
         'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
         'Color':["Red","Orange","Green","Blue","Indigo", "Violet","Black","White","Gold"],
         'UnUsedData': ['foo','bar','foo','bar','foo','bar','foo','bar','foo'],
         'Cost':[17,34,54,28,22,8,43,23,12]})
```

The merge statement is:

```
df_new = pd.merge(df1, df2[['ID','Color']], on ='ID', how ='left')
```

Which yields:

```
   ID  Version Cost   Color
0   1        1   17     Red
1   2        1   NaN  Orange
2   3        2   24   Green
3   4        2   21    Blue
4   5        1       Indigo
5   6        2    8  Violet
```

But what I want the output to look like is: [the cost column values change in index rows #s 1 and 4]

```
   ID  Version Cost   Color
0   1        1   17   Red
1   2        1   34   Orange
2   3        2   24   Green
3   4        2   21   Blue
4   5        1   22   Indigo
5   6        2    8   Violet
```

I could loop through the individual values of the cost column of df_new, and then lookup the value in df2 for each one that is blank or NaN, but it seems like there would be a more elegant/simpler approach. Maybe somehow using fillna()? The examples of that I've seen seem to be replacing NaN with a constant value, rather than something that varies according to the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) to get the first non-na information:

```
# merge
dfx = pd.merge(df1, df2[['ID','Color','Cost']], on ='ID', how ='left')

# replace empty space with NAN
dfx = dfx.replace("", np.nan)

# coalesce cost column to get first non NA value
dfx['Cost'] = dfx['Cost_x'].combine_first(dfx['Cost_y']).astype(int)

# remove the cols
dfx = dfx.drop(['Cost_x', 'Cost_y'], 1)
print(dfx)

   ID  Version   Color  Cost
0   1        1     Red    17
1   2        1  Orange    34
2   3        2   Green    24
3   4        2    Blue    21
4   5        1  Indigo    22
5   6        2  Violet     8
```

Comment: Good solution. Should be improved `dfx['Cost'] = dfx.pop('Cost_x').combine_first(dfx.pop('Cost_y')).astype(int)`, then last drop is not necessary

Comment: `df1.set_index('ID')['Cost'].replace('',np.nan).fillna(df2.set_index('ID')['Cost'])` @jezrael What do you think about this? Might be efficient not sure.

Comment: @Ch3steR - ya, but also is necessary add `Color` column to `df1`, so merge here should be fine, or double `map/replace`